# SQL Group Calculation Issues

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I am fairly new to writing reports in SQL and am having an issue with a % calculation. The query groups by department and employee, with calculations for YTDAccrued, YTDUsed and Reversing. Reversing is the calculation I am having an issue with (YTDUsed/YTDAccrued). The group by employee calculates fine it is the group by department calculation that doesn't appear to be working correctly, it is adding all the employee % calculations instead of doing a separate calculation for department only. How do I get the group "department" to calculate correctly? I have attached an image of the results.

```
    DECLARE @calyr varchar(4) Select @Calyr = '2014'

    SELECT asi_ptoytdbalances.Calyr,
       Department,
       asi_ptoytdbalances.EmpID,
       asi_ptoytdbalances.NameLast,
       asi_ptoytdbalances.NameFirst,
       SUM(CASE WHEN asi_PTOytdBalances.Description = 'Monthly Earned PTO' THEN Round((PTO),2) ELSE 0.00 END) AS YTDAccrued,
       Sum(CASE WHEN asi_PTOytdBalances.Description = 'PTO Used' THEN Round((PTO),2) * -1 ELSE 0.00 END)AS YTDUsed,
       Round((Sum(CASE WHEN asi_PTOytdBalances.Description = 'PTO Used' THEN PTO * -1 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN asi_PTOytdBalances.Description = 'Monthly Earned PTO' THEN PTO END)),4)AS Reversing
FROM ASI_PTOytdBalances
WHERE Calyr= @calyr
  AND Description <> ''
GROUP BY asi_ptoytdbalances.Calyr,
         asi_PTOytdBalances.Department,
         asi_PTOytdBalances.EmpID,
         asi_ptoytdbalances.NameLast,
         asi_ptoytdbalances.NameFirst
ORDER BY asi_PTOytdBalances.Department,
         asi_PTOytdBalances.EmpID
```

[PTO Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqcTo.jpg)

Comment: To add code formatting, edit your post, highlight the code, then press the curly braces (`{}`) at the top.

Comment: What would really help is table definitions and sample data. sqlfiddle.com would be a great place to start for that. Then we just need to know what you expect as output.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. In the screenshot, the group totals match the sums of the details below them. What exactly is calculated wrong? The sum is transitive operation in both math and SQL.